# Json.Net serialization turns object into string instead of class

Tags: c#, json.net

I have following class:

```
public partial class ArgumentBaseV2 : IArgumentBaseV2

{

    public string Name { get; set; } 


    public string Type { get; set; } 


    public object Value { get; set; } 
}

public class SimpleClass 
{
    public string MyString  { get; set; }
}
```

When my property Value is a class it still will be rendered as string.

```
public void Ser()
{
ArgumentBaseV2 myObject = new ArgumentBaseV2();
myObject.Name = "Test";
myObject.Type = "Test2";
myObject.Value = new SimpleClass() { MyString = "HelloWorld" };
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);
// result will be: { "Name":"Test", "Type":"Test2", Value: "{\"MyString\": \"HelloWorld\"}" }
// But I want: { "Name":"Test", "Type":"Test2", Value: {"MyString": "HelloWorld"} }
}
```

Comment: Was not able to reproduce. [Works](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NVSUDM) for me.

Comment: @GuruStron wow... that means its a bug on my end, but how? =/

Comment: Of course it is rendered as string. SerializeObject is serializing object to JSON string. Please check this link: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm

Comment: Do you use converter or anything what can cusomize serialization? But that would mean it's not [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you serialized the `Value` property separately. This happens if your code looks like this:

```
ArgumentBaseV2 myObject = new ArgumentBaseV2();
myObject.Name = "Test";
myObject.Type = "Test2";
myObject.Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new SimpleClass() { MyString = "HelloWorld" });
var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObject);
```

There is no other intuitive way (given that your codesample is complete) this could have happened

Comment: This or converter, or one of any other thing what can customize resulting json. Your answer basically say OP didn't show [mcve], means the question should be edited. This is why we have close-votes/flags.

Comment: What do you mean by "This is why we have close-votes"? Did you vote for closing the question? How did you do that?

Comment: I mean you shouldn't be posting your findings as the answer, since it's indicating the problem in question you should use [flags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) instead. [Vote-closing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) become available a bit later.